# How to test nested Serializers in Django Rest?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a ToDo App Django project, and so there are Task and TaskList models which are linked with a ManyToMany relation.
Inside my TaskSerializer, I have defined a nested TaskListSerializer which handles the reverse relation of a task's tasklists.
Everything is going well in real world, and the serialization and deserialization is ok.

This is what you should put request when updating a task (as json):

```
{
    "title": "hello",
    "tasklists": [
        {"pk": "b84d3375-0e09-4dd1-9809-f92d29d6aa36"},
        {"pk": "b84d3375-0e09-4dd1-9809-f92d29d6aa36"}
    ]
}
```

But inside the Tests, I want to test this serializer and, when I'm sending the put request the tasklists field is not sent to the view!

This is the test request:

```
path = self.task.get_absolute_api_url()
data = {
    "title": "hello",
    "tasklists": [
        {"pk": "b84d3375-0e09-4dd1-9809-f92d29d6aa36"},
        {"pk": "b84d3375-0e09-4dd1-9809-f92d29d6aa36"}
    ]
}
self.client.put(path, data)
```

But there is no tasklists field inside the validated_data and initial_data of view.(the title field is sent and validated)

I guess that the Renderer and json_encoder have the problem with this type of data.

**so how should the correct request data be inside a nested serializer test?**

***In General, How to test a Nested Serializer!***

Answer (score 1):

Testing a nested serializer in Django can be a bit tricky, especially when dealing with ManyToMany relationships. To test a nested serializer, you should ensure that the data you send in your test request is correctly formatted to match the serializer's expectations.

Here's how you can modify your test request data to ensure that the nested serializer is handled correctly:

```py
path = self.task.get_absolute_api_url()
data = {
    "title": "hello",
    "tasklists": [
        {"pk": "b84d3375-0e09-4dd1-9809-f92d29d6aa36"},
        {"pk": "b84d3375-0e09-4dd1-9809-f92d29d6aa36"}
    ]
}

# Convert the data to JSON since the Django test client sends JSON by default
json_data = json.dumps(data)

# Make the PUT request with the JSON data
self.client.put(path, json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

By using `json.dumps` to convert your data to JSON and specifying the content type as `'application/json'` in the `put` method, you ensure that the data is sent in the correct format for your serializer.

Additionally, when testing nested serializers, make sure that the data you are sending is correct and follows the structure expected by the serializer. In your case, the `tasklists` field in the `data` dictionary should match the structure expected by the nested serializer, which is a list of dictionaries with the key `"pk"`.

If the issue persists, you might want to check the view and serializer code to ensure that the nested serializer is correctly defined and handling the data as expected. You can also print or log the `data` received in the view during the test to inspect what is being received and processed.

Remember that testing nested serializers involves ensuring that the data sent in the test request is formatted correctly, and the nested relationships are properly handled in both the serializer and the view.